Analysis of an expression involving a function on $\mathbb R^n$. Related to limits, supremums and translations.
Let $n \in \mathbb N, \, 0 < \lambda < n$ and $1 \leqslant p < \infty$, consider the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and define the function $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ f(x) := |x|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}, $$
for every $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ ($f$ is defined arbitrarily at $x = 0$).
Question. Prove that
$$ \lim_{\xi \to 0} \, \, \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p \, dy \neq 0 $$
My attempt. Clearly, to prove the result it suffices to find a constant $c > 0$ such that
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p \, dy \geqslant c, $$
for every $\xi \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. This is an important observation because it allows us to work with any values of $x$ and $r$ that we find most adequate. I have tried the following:
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0}r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p \, dy \geqslant \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p \, dy, $$
where I have simply used the definition of supremum and took $x = 0$ and $r=1$. Furthermore, applying a simple inequality, it follows that
$$ \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p \, dy \geqslant 2^{-p} \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi)|^p \, dy - \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y)|^p \, dy. $$
Now let us compute the integrals of the right-hand side. For the latter one, using the theory of integration of radial functions, we have that
$$ \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y)|^p \, dy = \int_{B(0,1)} |y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}} \, dy = \int_0^1 t^{\lambda -1} \, dt = \frac{1}{\lambda}. $$
Now, I am having a hard time computing the first integral. Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Note that the final lower bound should be strictly positive!
Thanks for any help in advance.

About your approach. The function $f$ is bounded outside $B(0,1/2)$, i.e., $|f(y)| < C$ for some $C > 0$ and all $y \not \in B(0,1/2)$. Note that for every small enough $\xi$, the symmetric difference $B(0,1) \Delta B(-\xi,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,1/2)$ and $\lim_{\xi \to 0} Vol[B(0,1) \Delta B(-\xi,1)] = 0$. Moreover, doing the change of (dummy) variable $y - \xi \to y$, we get $\int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi)|^p dy = \int_{B(-\xi, 1)}|f(y)|^p dy$. Hence we estimate that
\begin{align}
 \left|\int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi)|^p dy - \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y)|^p dy \right| &\le \int_{B(0,1) \Delta B(-\xi, 1)} |f(y)|^p dy \\
&\le  C^p \, Vol[B(0,1) \Delta B(-\xi,1)] \overset{\xi \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0 \, . 
\end{align}
So you won't be able to prove a $\xi$-independent positive lower bound on $\int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|^p dy$ from a lower bound on the difference $\int_{B(0,1)} |f(y-\xi)|^p dy - \int_{B(0,1)} |f(y)|^p dy$.
About solving your question. Here's how to solve your question. For $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r > 0$,  let's define
$$g(\xi, x, r) :=  r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} | f(y - \xi) - f(y)|^p dy \; \mbox{ and } \; g(\xi) :=  \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, r > 0}{\sup} g(\xi, x, r) \, .$$
So your question amounts to proving that the limit $\lim_{\xi \to 0, \xi \neq 0} g(\xi)$ (i) exists, and (ii) is positive. (We need to assume $\xi \neq 0$, for clearly $g(0, x, r) = 0$ for all $x,r$.)
For this, note that for $l > 0$ and any rotation $R$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $g(l R\xi, l Rx, lr) = g(\xi, x, r)$. Indeed, writing $y = l Ry'$, we have $y \in B(l Rx, lr)$ iff $y' \in B(x,r)$ and
$$dy = d(l Ry') = l^n |\mathrm{det} \, R|dy' = l^n dy'\,;$$ moreover, $f(l Rz) = l^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}f(Rz) = l^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}}f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence
\begin{align}
g(l R\xi, l Rx, lr) &:=  (lr)^{-\lambda} \int_{y \in B(l Rx,lr)} | f(y - l R\xi) - f(y)|^p dy \\
&= (lr)^{-\lambda} \int_{y' \in B(x,r)} | f(l R(y' - \xi)) - f(l Ry')|^p \,d(l Ry') \\
&= (lr)^{-\lambda} \int_{y' \in B(x,r)} l^{\lambda - n}| f(y' - \xi) - f(y')|^p \, l^n |\mathrm{det} R| dy' \\
&= g(\xi, x, r)
\end{align}
From these invariance properties, it follows that for any $\xi, \xi' \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, we have $g(\xi) = g(\xi')$. (Hint: There exist $l > 0$ and a rotation $R$ such that $\xi' = lR\xi$. For every $ \eta < g(\xi)$, there exists $x,r$ such that $\eta < g(\xi, x, r) = g(lR\xi, lRx, lr) \le g(\xi')$.)
In other words, the function $\xi \mapsto g(\xi)$ is constant (and equals some number $c$) for $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$. It readily follows that the limit $\lim_{\xi \to 0, \xi \neq 0} g(\xi)$ exists (and equals $c$).
It remains to show that $c > 0$; for this, since $c = g(\xi) \ge g(\xi, x,r)$ for all $\xi, x, r$, it suffices to find $x,r$ such that $g(\xi, x, r) > 0$. A qualitative way to proceed is to note that for all $\xi, x,r$,  the integrand $y \mapsto |f(y-\xi) - f(y)|$ is (for $y \in B(x,r)$) everywhere nonnegative and positive and continuous on an open set, hence $g(\xi, x, r) > 0$ by general properties of the Lebesgue integral. A more quantitative way to proceed is, given $\xi$ of norm $1$ say, to consider $x = 0$ and $r = 1/3$. Indeed for these choices, for every $y \in B(0, 1/3)$, $y - \xi$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(0, 2/3)$. But for $y \in B(0,1/3)$, $f(y) \ge 3^{(n-\lambda)/p}$ (assuming we modify $f(0)$ to satisfy this inequality) and $f(y - \xi) \le (3/2)^{(n-\lambda)/p}$, hence
$$ g(\xi, 0, 1/3) \ge 3^{\lambda} \int_{B(0,1/3)} |3^{(n-\lambda)/p} - (3/2)^{(n-\lambda)/p}|^p dy  > 0 \, . $$

Thanks for you answer. I have some questions. For starters, after some calculations I was able to guarantee that $g(l\xi,lx,lr) = g(\xi,x,r)$ for any $\xi,x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $r,l > 0$. Now, how do you conclude from this that $ \xi \to g(\xi)$ is constant? That is, how do you guarantee that for $y,z \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $y \neq z$ we have $g(y) = g(z) = c$ for some constant $c$ ?

@xyz Hint: If  $x_y, r_y$ are such that $g(y, x_y, r_y)$ approximates $g(y)$, then fixing $l = z/y$, we see that $g(z, lx_y, lr_y)$ approximates $g(y)$, so $g(z) \gtrapprox g(y)$; as the approximation can be made arbitrarily good, we get $g(z) \geq g(y)$. Switching $y$ and $z$, we similarly get $g(y) \geq g(z)$.

Thanks for your clarification. I didn't go through the hint you've given but there is one question I would like to make before going into the details. By showing that $g(y)$ is constant for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$ aren't we automatically showing what we wish? Because if $g(\cdot)$ is constant it must be positive from properties of the Lebesgue integral and therefore it follows that $\lim_{\xi \to 0} , g(\xi) = c > 0$, no?

@xyz Sure, you can bypass the last hint in my answer by noting the integrand in $g(\xi, x, r)$ is everywhere nonnegative and positive at a point where it is continuous, hence its integral (and so $g(\xi, x, r)$) is positive.

What do you mean exactly by $g(y,x_y,r_y)$ approximates $g(y)$ ? And what do you understand by $z/y$ ? $y,z$ are elements of $\mathbb R^n$.

@xyz $g(y)$ is a supremum of the function $g(y, x, r)$ over the last two arguments $x,r$, so you can find $x_y, r_y$ so that $g(y, x_y, r_y)$ is 'as close to' $g(y)$ as you want. As for the $z/y$, you are absolutely right, and so the function $\xi \mapsto g(\xi)$ is a priori only constant along semi-infinite rays. I'll edit my answer to make this correction, thanks.

Ok so after your editions I understand most of your answer but I believe I am still missing the crucial step. More precisely, I don't understand how you obtain that $\xi \to g(\xi)$ is constant along rays $\mathbb R_+ \xi = { l\xi , \colon , l > 0}$ and I also don't understand how this implies that it is sufficient to consider $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $| \xi |=1$. Perhaps you can add details or provide hints for these steps ?

@xyz I edited my answer once more to make it a bit less implicit and a bit more exhaustive (and correct!). Hopefully this will help you clarify your remaining questions. (Knowing how to play with supremums and quotienting by equivalence classes is quite common in math, so I'll leave it to you to figure this out.)

It seems like you have just now added an extra step: more precisely, you added that for any rotation $R$ in $\mathbb R^n$ we have that $g(R\xi,Rx,r) = g(\xi,x,r)$. Now, how do you characterise a rotation in $\mathbb R^n$ ? This is something I am not familiar with and after searching it seems like there is an infinite number of rotations in $\mathbb R^n$. Is there any common characteristic between these rotations that allows one to guarantee that $g(R\xi,Rx,r) = g(\xi,x,r) ?$

@xyz Yes I added an extra step which should've been part of my initial answer; I apologize for the inconvenience. Rotations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the linear transformations $R$ that preserve the scalar product: $(Rv, Rw) = (v,w)$ for all $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. As matrices, these are the orthogonal matrices. It's a fact that any two vectors of unit norm $v,w$ are related by some rotation $R$: $w = Rv$. Thus any two nonzero vectors $v, w$ satisfy $w = l Rv$ with $l := |w|/|v|$. The equation $g(R\xi, Rx, r) = g(\xi, x, r)$ follows by the change of variable formula for Lebesgue integrals.

Sorry perhaps I am missing something really obvious but I still can't figure out how you obtain $g(R\xi,Rx,r) = g(\xi,x,r)$. I've tried the variable change $y = u + Rx - x$ but this doesn't seem to be the ideal one. Do you have any reference for the fact that any two vectors of unit norm $v,w$ are related by some rotation $R$ ?

@xyz Regarding the change of variable: $y \in B(Rx,r)$ iff there is $y' \in B(x,r)$ such that $y = Ry'$. So $dy = |det(R)|dy'$ where for rotations $|det(R)|=1$. Regarding the fact that any two unit norm vectors $v,w$ are related by a rotation, it suffices to prove that any unit vector $v$ is of the form $v = R_v e_1$ where $e_1 = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$ for some rotation $R_v$. To prove that, you need to know that a matrix $R_v$ is a rotation iff its columns form an orthogonal basis by unit vectors, so pick the first column of $R_v$ as $v$ and use e.g. Gram-Schmidt to complete the orthonormal basis.

Sorry I still am not able to understand the variable change. Can you edit the answer to provide further details ?
